# Query end of week and end of month data

Tags: sql, date, ms-access

In an Access database, if I have some stock data that is in the format of

```
DateFormatted      DateSeconds        CodeName       Close     
2000-01-01          946684800          AAA           1.01
2000-01-02          946771200          AAA           1.02
2000-01-03          946857600          AAA           1.03
2000-01-04          946944000          AAA           1.04
2000-01-05          947030400          AAA           1.05
2000-01-08          947289600          AAA           1.06
.
.
.
```

and note that it goes from `05` to `08`, as well as `DateFormatted` being a `Short Text`, rather than a `Date`. It seems like it will be almost impossible to query end of month (`01-31`) based upon a specific date in a WHERE clause, given the continuous date format. Instead, I am hoping that since such values may not exist in the database (as caused from weekends, public holidays, system errors etc), which will mean end of week may end on a Thursday, start of week may start on a Tuesday, end of month may be 3 days before the final day of the month, etc, there is a known method of obtaining such data in a query. How would this be possible?

Noting that in the above example, end of week will be `1.05` and end of month (if you keep continuing the trend of +0.01 for each day), will be `1.31`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the last row in the data for each month, you can use a correlated subquery:

```
select s.*
from stocks as s
where s.date = (select max(s2.date)
                from stocks as s2
                where s2.code = s.code and
                      year(s2.date) = year(s.date) and
                      month(s2.date) = month(s.date)
               );
```

You can do something similar with `datepart()` for weeks.

Comment: That does work well, my only issue is that it takes ~10+ seconds to run the query. I edited the question that may help to understand why, it could be because of a lot of substrings or something. But basically, the way I store the `Date`, is a `Short Text` - Reason being is so that loading the data into a C++ program does not need conversion from a `Struct` of int's to a string. - I have `CodeName`, `DateFormatted`, `DateSeconds` all Index'd.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking to get is the last stock value before a week/month ending date. So, in each case you need to find the date that this is. In your case for week-end it would be:

```
DateAdd("d",5-Weekday(StockDate,6),StockDate)
```

And for the month-end it would be:

```
DateSerial(Year(StockDate),Month(StockDate)+1,-1)
```

You would then use these two results in queries to get the value immediately before the selected date:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    S.StockCode, 
    DateAdd("d",5-Weekday(S.StockDate,6),S.StockDate) AS WeekEnding,
    (SELECT TOP 1 S1.StockClose FROM tblStock AS S1 WHERE S.StockCode=S1.StockCode AND S1.StockDate<=DateAdd("d",5-Weekday(S.StockDate,6),S.StockDate) ORDER BY S1.StockDate DESC) AS WeekClose
FROM tblStock AS S
```

And

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    S.StockCode, 
    DateSerial(Year(S.StockDate),Month(S.StockDate)+1,-1) AS MonthEnding,
    (SELECT TOP 1 S1.StockClose FROM tblStock AS S1 WHERE S.StockCode=S1.StockCode AND S1.StockDate<=DateSerial(Year(S.StockDate),Month(S.StockDate)+1,-1) ORDER BY S1.StockDate DESC) AS MonthClose
FROM tblStock AS S;
```

Note that I have renamed your fields, as `Date` is a reserved word in Access.

Regards,

Comment: This is most likely a fault in my design, however I have the dates stores as a string, and the sorting method is the dates stored as the timestamp of the corresponding dates. How can I get this query to work under those conditions? - The reason being is that retrieving the data via ODBC requires me to convert the date format in Access to an integer struct in C++, and then to convert that to a string for my program. This is slow and inefficient so I just stored the seconds since 1970 instead. This lets me retrieve the string date, as well as the seconds date to sort by, which is much faster.

Comment: Look at `CDate` or a combination of `Left/Mid/Right/DateSerial` to get the "dates" as proper DateType.

Comment: I tried DateValue(), considering it takes in a string, but the query is taking more than a minute for each, I wrapped each `S1.StockDate` in a DateValue, and the query has not moved in the status bar a pixel yet. The same deal with CDate.

Comment: This is all information that would be **really** useful to have known from the start. Please modify your question to include this information, including the raw data.

Comment: I actually added a `DateDate` field, with the date stored as an actual date. The query runs extemely slow, however. Also, when it does finish, the MonthEnding is the same for the past 12 rows for some reason.

Comment: I've edited the SQL statement to be `DateSerial(Year(S.StockDate),Month(S.StockDate)+1,-1)` which now indicates which table the Month is coming from.

Comment: Are there any tweeks to improve its performance? That query takes an unbelievable amount of time to run. I have StockDate, StockCode, Close all indexed