# SQL - Select MAX or TOP 1 FROM each month

Tags: sql, date, filter, max

I have a query that literally does nothing helpful, but hopefully paints the picture of what I am trying to accomplish.

```
SELECT * 
FROM Tbl_StockData 
WHERE Date <= DateSerial(YEAR(Date), MONTH(Date) + 1, 1) - 1);
```

Which basically gets all values where the date is <= the end of the month. From here, I want to select the top (or latest) day from each month of the query. I.e, the current query produces

```
CodeName    Date    
----------------------
14D         2018-09-12
14D         2018-09-13
14D         2018-09-14
14D         2018-09-17
14D         2018-09-18
14D         2018-09-19
14D         2018-09-20
14D         2018-09-21
14D         2018-09-24
14D         2018-09-25
14D         2018-09-26
14D         2018-09-27
14D         2018-09-28
14D         2018-10-01
.
.
.
```

And note that it is not just `14D` listed here, there are many more. What you can see here is that the end of month data is not always the `31`'st or `30`'th, so for each new month, for each new CodeName, I want to obtain the last value in the given month, for all months.

Something that achieves this would look like

```
CodeName    Date
----------------------
14D         2018-09-28
14D         2018-10-31
14D         2018-11-30
14D         2018-12-31
14D         2019-01-31
14D         2019-02-28
.
.
.
```

Okay, well I got a bit unlucky with that one given then last 5 dates are, in fact, the EOM date, but hopefully the point is clear. If I were to select the MAX or TOP of the days in a given month, I would like it to return me the last date in the data set of the month, for all months, for all CodeNames.

Comment: How does this differ from your previous question:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68234217/query-end-of-week-and-end-of-month-data?

Comment: Because the solutions there are specialised, this is selecting the top day of a month. It does't have to be used specifically for that questions use case.